# Opening links with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have written some Java codes which opens a URL and takes some information from classes and stores it into database, but I need to open several other URLs and I am not able to perform this function. I am using the Selenium library to open my URL.

Below is my code for to open a URL.

```
public class Notafiscal {

    private static final String BASE = "https://www.nf-eletronica.com.br/NFE.asp?a=41241241242412412412412&b=T";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        insert(driver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you able to do this?  Is this not working in some way?  Be specific.  By the way, there is a Portugues-speaking Stack Overflow at https://pt.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to get better for my another questions.                                             
But my doubt is how to open more than one URL and run my code.
My code works "perfectly" the way I want it, it just does not open multiple URLs, and that's my need.

Comment: Can you add the code where you are opening up multiple URLs? Any errors?

Comment: I need to set up as urls inside the "private static String BASE" because I use it as the base to open the url I want

Comment: >public class Urls {
  
    >private String[] testurl = {
    >                            "www.nf-eletronica.com.br/NFE.asp?>a=21123312123312312321&b=T",
  >                              "www.nf-eletronica.com.br/NFE.asp?>a=412412412412142412412421&b=T",
  >                              "www.nf-eletronica.com.br/NFE.asp?>a=41255125215525125125125121525&b=T",
  >                              "www.nf-eletronica.com.br/NFE.asp?>a=111252525515251251251251251251252&b=T",
                                };'